# What is the proper approach on persisting a new object? Receiving a built json object with @RequestBody or receiving many @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, backend

In order to save a new object like i.e a User object:

```
class User {

private String name;
private String email;

}
```

Should I ask my client to submit a @RequestBody like this:

```
{
"name":"Josh",
"email":"josh@kmail.com"
}
```

Or maybe should just ask for some @RequestParams like this:

```
/api/user?name=Josh&&email=josh@kmail.com
```

And create a method that builds the object from these params?
I am dealing with some complex objects in my project if it has anything to do with my question.

Thanks your help.

Comment: `@RequestBody` is a good option because it allows to map your payload with your object directly.

Comment: Use `@RequestBody` if you want a payload, use `@ModelAttribute` to automatically bind request parameters to an object. Either will work with a `User` object (assuming that) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Both your approaches would work - but the standard way is definitely using:

```
POST @RequestBody JSON of { user } to /users
```

GET would *technically* work - but using the HTTP method GET implies that the action is idempotent, meaning it will not change the underlying data (from the client's viewpoint) - and this is almost certainly not the case when creating a new User.

In addition, the current User object is simple enough to be represented by query string parameters - but that may change in the future, when a User could contain various contact information such as addresses.

Answer (score 1):

@RequestBody and @RequestParam both would work fine, it's on you as a backend developer you need to decide how you want to accept the data and @RequestBody is the recommended way to accept such object.

Actually, you can use a Jackson Dependency for binding the data and if you are using spring-boot then it automatically does that for you.

What is Data Binding?
Conversion of JSON object to Java POJO or vice-versa according to our need.

@RequestBody will pass down the whole object to you whereas in @RequestParam you will have to accept the values individually and then create an object and set the values. So we can compare now we have lesser work to do if we decide to work with @RequestBody.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC has 2 annotations to handle mapping to an object.

- [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) to map a request payload to an object.
- [`@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) to map request parameters (automatically) to an object.

So actually both can automatically map to your `User` object.

```java
@PostMapping
public User register(@RequestBody User user) {}
```

or

```java
@PostMapping
public User register(@ModelAttribute User user) {}
```

The first will use the payload, the second will use the request parameters to create the `User` object. So both will work, but serve different use cases.